# Tidy button on Stack Overflow code snippet tool breaks optional chaining in JavaScript code

Tags: bug, status-review, stack-snippets, tidy

Bug report:

Create a code snippet and try and use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). Click <kbd>Tidy</kbd> and see it add erroneous spaces to the code around the `?` in the optional chaining portion.

```js
//optional chainging syntax

document.querySelector('#foo')?.click();

//After tidy:

document.querySelector('#foo') ? .click();

// Syntax error!
```

Comment: Duplicate on MSE: "[Snippet Tidy breaks Optional Chaining](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348290/271271)"